# Discord ticket system

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm currently experiencing an issue with my script where after restarting it, only the ticket button is functional while the verify button is not. I'm looking to get some help on how to resolve this issue.
Here are some details about the problem:

The script is designed to create two types of tickets. One for general help, and one for verification.

The ticket button is responsible for generating and displaying the ticket, while the verify button is for the verification part.

The script runs smoothly when initially executed, but after restarting it, the verify button stops working. I need to delete the old message with the verify button and create it again, while the ticket button works perfectly.

Any help or suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Below is my code, role_id, and guild_id are predefined at the beginning.

````
class ticket_launcher(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(timeout = None)
        self.cooldown = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(1, 1, commands.BucketType.member)
    
    @discord.ui.button(label = " Create a Ticket", style = discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id = "ticket_button")
    async def ticket(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        interaction.message.author = interaction.user
        retry = self.cooldown.get_bucket(interaction.message).update_rate_limit()
        if retry: return await interaction.response.send_message(f"Slow down! Try again in {round(retry, 1)} seconds!", ephemeral = True)
        ticket = utils.get(interaction.guild.text_channels, name = f"ticket-{interaction.user.name.lower().replace(' ', '-')}-{interaction.user.discriminator}")
        if ticket is not None: await interaction.response.send_message(f"You already have a ticket open at {ticket.mention}!", ephemeral = True)
        else:
            if type(client.ticket_mod) is not discord.Role: 
                client.ticket_mod = interaction.guild.get_role(role_id)
            overwrites = {
                interaction.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = False),
                interaction.user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = True, read_message_history = True, send_messages = True, attach_files = True, embed_links = True),
                interaction.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = True, send_messages = True, read_message_history = True), 
                client.ticket_mod: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = True, read_message_history = True, send_messages = True, attach_files = True, embed_links = True),
            }
            try: channel = await interaction.guild.create_text_channel(name = f"ticket-{interaction.user.name}-{interaction.user.discriminator}", overwrites = overwrites, reason = f"Ticket for {interaction.user}")
            except: return await interaction.response.send_message("Ticket creation failed! Make sure I have `manage_channels` permissions!", ephemeral = True)
            await channel.send(f"{client.ticket_mod.mention}, {interaction.user.mention} created a ticket!", view = main())
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"I've opened a ticket for you at {channel.mention}!", ephemeral = True)

class verify_launcher(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(timeout = None)
        self.cooldown = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(1, 1, commands.BucketType.member)
    
    @discord.ui.button(label = " Verify", style = discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id = "verify_button")
    async def verify(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        interaction.message.author = interaction.user
        retry = self.cooldown.get_bucket(interaction.message).update_rate_limit()
        if retry: return await interaction.response.send_message(f"Slow down! Try again in {round(retry, 1)} seconds!", ephemeral = True)
        verify = utils.get(interaction.guild.text_channels, name = f"verify-{interaction.user.name.lower().replace(' ', '-')}-{interaction.user.discriminator}")
        if verify is not None: await interaction.response.send_message(f"You already have a verify open at {verify.mention}!", ephemeral = True)
        else:
            if type(client.ticket_mod) is not discord.Role: 
                client.ticket_mod = interaction.guild.get_role(role_id)
            overwrites = {
                interaction.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = False),
                interaction.user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = True, read_message_history = True, send_messages = True, attach_files = True, embed_links = True),
                interaction.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = True, send_messages = True, read_message_history = True), 
                client.ticket_mod: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = True, read_message_history = True, send_messages = True, attach_files = True, embed_links = True),
            }
            try: channel = await interaction.guild.create_text_channel(name = f"verify-{interaction.user.name}-{interaction.user.discriminator}", overwrites = overwrites, reason = f"Verify for {interaction.user}")
            except: return await interaction.response.send_message("Verify creation failed! Make sure I have `manage_channels` permissions!", ephemeral = True)
            await channel.send(f"{client.ticket_mod.mention}, {interaction.user.mention} want to verify his/hers account.\n:flag_ro:\nÎn videoclip vă este prezentat întregul proces de verificare.\n\n:flag_us:\nThe entire verification process is shown in the video.\n4", view = main())
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"I've opened a verify for you at {channel.mention}!", ephemeral = True)

class confirm(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(timeout = None)
        
    @discord.ui.button(label = "Confirm", style = discord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id = "confirm")
    async def confirm_button(self, interaction, button):
        try: await interaction.channel.delete()
        except: await interaction.response.send_message("Channel deletion failed! Make sure I have `manage_channels` permissions!", ephemeral = True)

class call(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.called = False

    @discord.ui.button(label="Call Staff", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id="call")
    async def call_button(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        if not self.called:
            # Get the role object with the desired ID
            role = interaction.guild.get_role(1027193856439111799)

            # Send a message in the channel where the interaction occurred
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"The staff team has been called! {role.mention}",
                                                    allowed_mentions=discord.AllowedMentions(roles=True))

            # Remove the "Call Staff" button from the view
            self.remove_item(button.custom_id)
            self.called = True


class main(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(timeout = None)
        self.call_staff_pressed = False
    
    @discord.ui.button(label = "Close Ticket", style = discord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id = "close")
    async def close(self, interaction, button):
        embed = discord.Embed(title = "Are you sure you want to close this ticket?", color = discord.Colour.blurple())
        embed.set_footer(text=footer_text, icon_url=footer_url)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed = embed, view = confirm(), ephemeral = True)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Call Staff", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, custom_id="call")
    async def call_staff(self, interaction, button):
        if not self.call_staff_pressed:
            self.call_staff_pressed = True
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Want to call a staff?", color=discord.Colour.blurple())
            embed.set_footer(text=footer_text, icon_url=footer_url)
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=call(), ephemeral=True)
            self.remove_item(button.custom_id)
        

    @discord.ui.button(label = "Transcript", style = discord.ButtonStyle.secondary, custom_id = "transcript")
    async def transcript(self, interaction, button):
        await interaction.response.defer()
        if os.path.exists(f"{interaction.channel.id}.md"):
            return await interaction.followup.send(f"A transcript is already being generated!", ephemeral = True)
        with open(f"{interaction.channel.id}.md", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(f"# Transcript of {interaction.channel.name}:\n\n".encode('utf-8', errors='ignore').decode('utf-8'))
            async for message in interaction.channel.history(limit = None, oldest_first = True):
                created = datetime.strftime(message.created_at, "%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M:%S")
                if message.edited_at:
                    edited = datetime.strftime(message.edited_at, "%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M:%S")
                    f.write(f"{message.author} on {created}: {message.clean_content} (Edited at {edited})\n")
                else:
                    f.write(f"{message.author} on {created}: {message.clean_content}\n")
            generated = datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y at %H:%M:%S")
            f.write(f"\n*Generated at {generated} by {client.user}*\n*Date Formatting: MM/DD/YY*\n*Time Zone: UTC*")
        with open(f"{interaction.channel.id}.md", 'rb') as f:
            await interaction.followup.send(file = discord.File(f, f"{interaction.channel.name}.md"))
        os.remove(f"{interaction.channel.id}.md")
    
class aclient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        intents = discord.Intents.default()
        intents.message_content = True
        super().__init__(intents = intents)
        self.synced = False #we use this so the bot doesn't sync commands more than once
        self.ticket_mod = role_id


    async def setup_hook(self):
            self.add_view(ticket_launcher())
            self.add_view(main())

client = aclient()
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(guild = discord.Object(id=guild_id), name = 'verify', description='Launches the verify system') #guild specific slash command
@app_commands.default_permissions(manage_guild = True)
@app_commands.checks.cooldown(3, 1, key = lambda i: (i.guild_id))
@app_commands.checks.bot_has_permissions(manage_channels = True)
async def verifying(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Verfiy", description = "\nPentru verificare reactioneaza mai jos cu .\n\n\nFor verification react below with .", color = discord.Colour.green())
    embed.set_footer(text=footer_text, icon_url=footer_url)
    await interaction.channel.send(embed = embed, view = verify_launcher())
    await interaction.response.send_message("Verify system launched!", ephemeral = True)

@tree.command(guild = discord.Object(id=guild_id), name = 'ticket', description='Launches the ticketing system') #guild specific slash command
@app_commands.default_permissions(manage_guild = True)
@app_commands.checks.cooldown(3, 1, key = lambda i: (i.guild_id))
@app_commands.checks.bot_has_permissions(manage_channels = True)
async def ticketing(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Ticket Help", description = "\nDacă ai nevoie de ajutor reacționează mai jos cu .\n\n\nIf you need help react below with .", color = discord.Colour.blue())
    embed.set_footer(text=footer_text, icon_url=footer_url)
    await interaction.channel.send(embed = embed, view = ticket_launcher())
    await interaction.response.send_message("Ticketing system launched!", ephemeral = True)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change this part

```
async def setup_hook(self):
            self.add_view(ticket_launcher())
            self.add_view(main())
```

to contain

```
self.add_view(verify_launcher())
```